# Selector implementation in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsview

I'm trying to define a NSRect tracking. On a new project I'm just adding several lines to the ViewController.swift file:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let tester = Test()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addTrackingRect(view.bounds, owner: tester, userData: nil, assumeInside: false)
    }
}

class Test: NSObject {
    @objc func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("mouseEntered")
    }
    @objc func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("mouseExited")
    }
    override func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {
        print("aSelector: -> \(aSelector) -> \(super.responds(to: aSelector))")
        return super.responds(to: aSelector)
    }
}
```

The result is that the app crashes with:

> aSelector: -> Optional(mouseEntered:) -> false
>   2017-11-12 00:18:56.204723+0200 test21[19694:1744132] *** Assertion failure in -[NSWindow _setTrackingRect:inside:owner:userData:useTrackingNum:install:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.10.101/AppKit.subproj/winTrackingAreas.m:408
>   2017-11-12 00:18:56.207360+0200 test21[19694:1744132] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
>   2017-11-12 00:18:56.207382+0200 test21[19694:1744132] [General] Window: target of tracking rect doesnt understand -mouseEntered: or -mouseExited messages

So my question is - how to define a valid selector ???

I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Swift documentation for [`addTrackingRect(_:owner:userData:assumeInside:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483668-addtrackingrect) is pretty misleading; it says that the owner should respond

> to both `mouseEntered(with:)` and `mouseExited(with:)`.

However, what it really *should* say is that it needs to respond to the selectors `mouseEntered:` & `mouseExited:`, because by default, the selector for a method such as `mouseEntered(with:)` is `mouseEnteredWith:`, as the argument label is part of the signature.

So, to solve this problem, you can either:

1. Remove the argument labels:

   ```
   class Test : NSObject {
     @objc func mouseEntered(_ event: NSEvent) {
       print("mouseEntered")
     }

     @objc func mouseExited(_ event: NSEvent) {
       print("mouseExited")
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```
2. Define the selectors manually:

   ```
   class Test : NSObject {
     @objc(mouseEntered:) func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
       print("mouseEntered")
     }

     @objc(mouseExited:) func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
       print("mouseExited")
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```